# regex: allow certain characters within a variable search string

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I'm trying to to use regex in **js** for searching a name out of a list of names.
I want the user to allow to throw certain characters (`-`, `_`, space) in their input and still find the right result.

e.g.

if the name is `"New York"`, there should be a match for:

```
"New York"
"newyork"
"new york"
"new-york"
"new_york"
" New york"
```

Thats of course not all possibilities. Im really not sure how to approach this.

**Edit**
Thanks for the fast answers.

I think i didnt state my question clear enough. My goal is to find if a input string is contained within a list of strings. The characters of the input have to match the elements from the list but these certain characters are ignored.

Comment: The regex `/\s?new[\s_-]?york/i` should meet all your tests, but could be more specific. Do you want to allow any amount of whitespace/dash/underscores in between? Any amount in front? Or only one?

Comment: Sould `"-ne wy_--ork"` be matched?

Comment: Paste more examples. What should be ignored and what not.

Comment: yes ibrahim mahrir, it should be

the thing is it should not only work for new york, but for any city name that might be in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should strip the allowed characters from both the query string and the items from the list, then do a simple comparaison of the rest of both strings:

```
var regex = /[-_ ]/g;                                            // regex containing the allowed chars (g modifier required)

var query = "New York";                                          // the query string to be used for searching
var list = [/* list of words */];                                // the list to get matches from

query = query.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase();                  // remove the allowed chars from the query and convert it to lowercases

var matches = list.filter(function(word) {                       // for each word in the list
    return query === word.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase();      // remove the allowed chars, convert to lowercases, then compare with the altered query (if they matched then return true)
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var list = ["New York", "New Fork", "newyork", "new york", "new-york", "new_york", " New york", "new orky", "---n-e_w-   y____o_-rk_-_-_-"];

var regex = /[-_ ]/g;

var query = prompt("Enter the query yo!", "Ne---w-_---York") || "";

query = query.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase();

var matches = list.filter(function(word) {
    return query === word.replace(regex, "").toLowerCase();
});

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: `\s?\w+[\s-_]?\w+`

**Details**:

`\s` matches any whitespace character equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ]

`\w` matches any word character equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

`+` Matches between one and unlimited times

`[]` Match a single character present in the list

`?` Matches between zero and one times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZnSgl/2)

Answer (score 2):

You're right, Regex is perfect for this.

```
var name = 'New~York';
if (name.match(/^[a-zA-Z-_ ]+$/g) == null) {
    alert('Name contains invalid characters');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a regex pattern based on the target string. I would convert all strings to lowercase before comparisons using .toLowerCase(), split by spaces using .split(' '), and then build the regex from the partsby using [\s_-]* in front, behind, and in the spaces.

```
[\s_-]*new[\s_-]*york[\s_-]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

I finally got an solution by replacing the characters both in the search as well as in the target strings and matching them against each other:

```
regex = new RegExp(input.replace(/[-\s_'´`]+/i, ''), "i");
if (regex.test(target.replace(/[-\s_'´`]+/i, ''))){ ... }
```